# Is currency symbol enough to figure out the culture

Tags: web-app, formatting, culture, currency

I want to figure out a culture by passing just the currency symbol, however, I'm not sure if that is a good method?

I was also wondering if the currency formatting is dictated by culture or by the used currency? I suspect that using just the currency symbol will overlap multiple cultures and each one can have different currency formats. However, currently, my only option is just using the currency symbol.

Comment: Could you perhaps add the business case (or problem) for doing this? Could you also provide us with the research that you've already done and what's unclear?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean that you're trying to find out the "country" based on the currency symbol?? Culture is made up of many things including dialect, music, arts, social habits, cuisine, and folklore, which you certainly won't get through the currency symbol.

Comment: as @DasBeasto said. Are you sure you mean culture and not nationality? Because if you mean culture, then it's a really broad description, and either way the answer is **no**

Comment: A quick Google search will tell you: "Dollar (often represented by the peso and dollar sign $) is the name of several currencies, including those of Australia, Belize, Brunei, Canada, Hong Kong, Jamaica, Namibia, New Zealand, Singapore, Suriname, Taiwan, the United States, and previously Zimbabwe. The U.S. dollar is the official currency of East Timor, Ecuador, El Salvador, Federated States of Micronesia, Marshall Islands, Palau, the Caribbean Netherlands, and for banknotes."

Comment: @DasBeasto: In some programming libraries, "culture" is indeed the term used, as it doesn't quite match countries, either.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it will be enough to capture all the cultures. Currently under Euro there is a wide spectrum of countries and cultures. I think using flags would be more appropriate to differentiate between cultures.

Answer (score 0):

unlike currencies or countries, culture is a thing that has no definite borders. there will always be overlap of cultures for different groups. Could you provide more context on the problem you are trying to solve?

e.g. the number system we use 1234567890 is knowns as the Hindu arabic system.

"the Hindu numeral system[1] or Hindu–Arabic numeral system[2] is a positional decimal numeral system, nowadays the most common symbolic representation of numbers in the world. It was invented between the 1st and 4th centuries by Indian mathematicians. The system was adopted by Persian mathematicians (Muḥammad ibn Mūsā al-Khwārizmī's c. 825 book On the Calculation with Hindu Numerals) and Arab mathematicians (Al-Kindi's c. 830 volumes On the Use of the Hindu Numerals) by the 9th century. It later spread to medieval Europe by the High Middle Ages."